# Failing to execute tests in Bitrise for debug variant

Tags: ios, react-native, testing, detox, packager

#### Description

I'm using Bitrise to run Detox tests. The build command runs ok and is a success. But the test command always fails.

---

**Running locally:**

- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.debug` without starting the packager: 'No bundle URL present' error
- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.debug` with the packager: Opens the packager and everything runs OK.
- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.release` without the packager: works fine.
- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.release` with the packager: works fine.

---

**Running in Bitrise:**

- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.debug --cleanup` without starting the packager: 'No bundle URL present' error
- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.debug --cleanup` with the packager:

  `Verify tests are up
  "before all" hook:
  Error: Timeout of 120000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/Users/vagrant/git/e2e/tests.spec.js)`
- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.release --cleanup` without the packager: works fine.
- Command `detox test -c ios.sim.release --cleanup` with the packager: works fine.

**Disclaimer**
With/Without the packager means the variable `RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER` equals `false/true`, respectively.

---

#### The package.json file

```
"ios.sim.debug": {
    "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PROJECT_NAME.app",
    "build": "export RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=true && xcodebuild -workspace ios/PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme INTEGRATION_SCHEME -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "name": "iPhone 7"
},
"ios.sim.release": {
    "binaryPath": "ios/build/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/PROJECT_NAME.app",
    "build": "export RCT_NO_LAUNCH_PACKAGER=true && xcodebuild -workspace ios/PROJECT_NAME.xcworkspace -scheme PRODUCTION_SCHEME -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator -derivedDataPath ios/build",
    "type": "ios.simulator",
    "name": "iPhone 7 Plus"
},
```

#### The bitrise.yml file

```
_init_install:
    steps:
    - activate-ssh-key@3.1.1:
        run_if: '{{getenv "SSH_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY" | ne ""}}'
    - git-clone@4.0.11: {}
    - script@1.1.5:
        inputs:
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            # fail if any commands fails
            set -e
            # debug log
            set -x

            # write your script here
            brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies node
            brew install node@8
            brew link --overwrite --force node@8
    - yarn@0.0.7: {}

_detox_tests:
    steps:
    - npm@0.9.0:
        title: Install Detox CLI
        inputs:
        - command: install -g detox-cli
    - npm@0.9.0:
        title: Install React-Native CLI
        inputs:
        - command: install -g react-native-cli
    - script@1.1.5:
        title: Install Detox Utils
        inputs:
        - content: |-
            #!/bin/bash
            brew tap facebook/fb
            export CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
            brew install fbsimctl
            brew tap wix/brew
            brew install applesimutils --HEAD
    - script@1.1.5:
        title: Detox - Build Debug App
        inputs:
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            detox build -c ios.sim.debug
    - script@1.1.5:
        title: Detox - Run E2E Tests
        inputs:
        - content: |-
            #!/usr/bin/env bash
            detox test -c ios.sim.debug --cleanup
    - deploy-to-bitrise-io@1.3.10: {}

test_ios:
    before_run:
    - _init_install
    after_run:
    - _detox_tests
    steps:
    - cocoapods-install@1.7.2:
        inputs:
        - podfile_path: ios/Podfile
    - resource-archive@2.0.1:
        inputs:
        - extract_to_path: "$HOME/Documents/FacebookSDK/"
        - archive_url:https://origincache.facebook.com/developers/resources/?id=facebook-ios-sdk-current.zip
- certificate-and-profile-installer@1.9.3: {}
```

```

---

#### Detox, Node, Device, Xcode and macOS Versions

- Detox: v7.4.3
- React Native: v0.51.0
- Node: v9.4.0
- Device: iPhone 7 (simulator)
- Xcode: Version 9.3 (9E145)
- macOS: 10.13.3 (17D102)

---

#### Device and verbose Detox logs

1. Error `detox test -c ios.sim.debug --cleanup` with the packager

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/FpyBsPym)

2. File `detox.last_launch_app_log.err` prints:

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Jd0T7CDz)

---

### TL;DR

I get an error when running Detox with Bitrise. The command `detox test -c ios.sim.debug --cleanup` should open a packager but looks like it's not doing it.

The version that is needed to test is the Debug one, no other options. Maybe I missed something about the installation, but all the files were checked with official docs and other examples and are the identical.

Related issues: [742](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/742), [749](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/749), [740](https://github.com/wix/detox/issues/740)